# How do I iterate through through specific pairs of a list - Python

Tags: python, list, loops

Consinder the following example:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Is there a simple way to produce the following output

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I tried different methods, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
for v, w in zip(a[:-1], a[1:]):
    print(v, w)
```

but i always get the same result:

The new line always starts with the last number of the line before

```
1 2
2 3
3 4 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
for i in range(0, len(values), 2):
    print(values[i], values[i+1])
```

Might want to add a check though that `i+1` exists, or turn around the logic:

```
for i in range(1, len(values), 2):
    print(values[i-1], values[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using slicing with step argument.

**Ex:**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
for v, w in zip(a[0::2], a[1::2]):
    print(v, w)
```

**Output:**

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
for v, w in zip(a[0:-1:2], a[1::2]):
    print(v, w)
```

output

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```